# ActiveMQ - possibility of session/transaction replication

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ 5.12.1 with Master/Slave configuration and SQL DB - we have not much load, but we have long running queue consumers - between few seconds and few hours.

JMS Messages are persistent and sessions are transactional.

I have listener that is processing a message from a queue in a transaction and this process takes few minutes. When during this time failover takes place, the processing will finish, but the JMS Transaction will get rolled back due to failover.

Is is possible to configure ActiveMQ in a way, that failover will also include running transactions - so that they can successfully finish after reconnecting to new Master ?

Comment: Nope you cannot configure that, you need to handle the possibility of TX rollback client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that the broker or the client will allow.  Since there's no way to know exactly what was inflight at the time of the failover either on the client end or the broker side the only safe thing to do is mark the TX as failed and roll it back otherwise the client could think that an ack it sent made it when in fact it did not, or the broker could assume the client got a message it sent when in fact that didn't happen either.

You client needs to account for the fact that a TX operation can and will be rolled back at times.